# Not able to access URL manually in ReactJS build

Tags: reactjs, build

I have created build using `Webpack 4.2.0`. But I'm not able to access URLs directly without landing to `index` page.

My WebPack Config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
// require('react-select/dist/react-select.css')
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');
var CSS_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'public/css');
// const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    // Configure HtmlPlugin to use our own index.html file
    // as a template.
    // Check out https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin
    // for the full list of options.
    new HtmlPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
     minimize: true
   })
  ],
  module : {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
         enforce: "pre",
         include : APP_DIR,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        include : CSS_DIR
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Index.js

```
render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

APP.JS

```
 const Main = () => (
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
          <Route path='/listing' component={Listing}/>
          <Route path='/product/:id' component={Product}/>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    )
```

In Build folder, two files created.

```
 - index.html
 - bundle.js
```

And I have used http-server to open React Build

```
./node_modules/.bin/http-server build -p 3007
```

But In browser, it will throw 404 if I access URL `localhost:3007/contact` directly.

What is right way to deploy this for production which can be accessed via url say `www.reactapp.com/contact`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your server to serve your `index.html` for all `GET` requests. ReactRouter just changes the navigation history, you don't actually leave the page when the route changes. Currently, your server is just serving the `index.html` page for the `/` route. Configure it to serve the page on all routes and you will be able to visit the routes by access their urls directly.